# Converting string to split, to integer

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to  split a string input into integer format.

Example:

```
x = "9 39 20 38 4 12"
```

If I use `x.to_i`, it will return only the first number:

```
9
```

If I use `x.split(' ').to_i` I get:

```
 undefined method `to_i'
```

How would I go about this?

Trying to start solving algorithms on:

```
 https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/simple-array-sum
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `split` changes the object to an Array, you need to iterate over the array items and use `to_i` on each. Luckily there is a function for this:

`x.split(' ').map(&:to_i)`

which is short for:

`x.split(' ').map { |num| num.to_i }`

Comment: To avoid problems with multiple spaces you may use `x.split(/\s+/)`.instead `x.split(' ')`.

Comment: @knut, by default, `split` is the same as `split(' ')`. `split(' ')` automatically manages multiple whitespace between words, so it's adequate to use the simple form `split` unless you've changed the default `$;` value. `"a \t b".split #=> ["a", "b"]`.

Comment: @theTinMan Thanks for the remark - I wasn't aware of this. (I have to test my thoughts before I post them next time ;) )